# How to insert null or empty value to decimal column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, decimal

If it is a string column, I can insert null or empty value with `''`, but what about the decimal column, `Null` or `-99999`? Thanks so much for any advice.

Comment: For a decimal, just go with null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert null values into the table with a column type integer. Empty_string and null is the same in oracle.

Eg:

```
create table t(x int)

insert into t values('')
insert into t values(null)

select count(*),count(x)
  from t
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e7653cf554a9e19a8ae47f1c101218ff

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is nothing but the value that is missing or not available.

You can insert null in any null-allowed column in database regardless of its data type. For `string` `''` (empty value) is considered as `null`. There is no such stuff for `number`.

```
Create table test
(id number,
Name varchar2(10),
Address clob,
Zip integer);

Insert into test
Values(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert empty value `('')` which will throw the error following error, instead you can insert `NULL` values.

> converting data type varchar to numeric.

```
INSERT INTO TBL (DeciClm) VALUES(NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are right, so is @George Joseph, I am sorry I set his answer as the correct one（He has sample code, and the answer was earlier）, I voted your answer too